# How to add widgets to specific pages in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, widgets

I created a static block. Then made a widget using that static block. And now i want to add that to the layout of some pages.

If i choose display on all pages, it works on all pages. But as of now i first only want it on two pages, about us and the homepage, but how to do that in widgets? I don't see homepage or about us in the specific page drop down ?

Comment: would you display it in category page ?

Answer (score 0):

Go To your specific **CMS Pages** for example **about us**

In content select widget option choose widget type cms static block

select your specific **static block** and insert it in content.

Comment: thanks for that. i know it can be done like this. but i would like to specify the page i want it to be shown on in the widget layout menu. Not going to every page and add it like you said. or is that not possible?